# Typescript not working in admistrator mode but works in normal user mode

Tags: typescript

Installed the typescript as global using npm command
npm install -g typescript

I am trying to initialize typescript config using following command
tsc --init

Above command works when open command prompt in normal mode.
refer [normal user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yIjY.png)

Above command is not working, when I open command prompt as administrator. I tried installing the typescript again in the administrator mode. typescript installation is completed but init command did not work.

refer 
[admin mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uCPK.png)
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Is the admin user the same as the normal user unde which tsc was installed ? `npm` will install things under the current user with the `-g` flag not for the whole system

Comment: Normal user and admin users are two different users. they are not same. installed the typescript using both the users still not working. Please refer the images

Comment: You may need to add the location of tsc to the PATH when logged in as an admin.